# Error while implementing Word2Vec model with embedding_vector

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, gensim, word2vec

I'm getting an **AttributeError** while trying to implement with embedding_vector:

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
embeddings_dictionary = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('model', binary=True)

embedding_matrix = np.zeros((vocab_size, 100))
for word, index in tokenizer.word_index.items():
    embedding_vector = embeddings_dictionary.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        embedding_matrix[index] = embedding_vector
```

> AttributeError: 'Word2VecKeyedVectors' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: What do you understand from that error message? Also, always share the entire error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `gensim`'s `KeyedVectors` abstraction does not offer a `get()` method. (What docs or example are you following that suggests it does?)

You can use standard Python `[]`-indexing, eg:

```
embedding_dictionary[word]
```

Though, there isn't really a reason for your loop copying each vector into your own `embedding_matrix`. The `KeyedVectors` instance already has a raw array, with each vector in a row, in the order of the `KeyedVectors` `.index2entity` list – in its `vectors` property:

```
embedding_dictionary.vectors
```

Comment: Actually, I am trying to add this to embedding layer: `embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size, 100, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=maxlen , trainable=False)`

Comment: Ok, maybe that makes sense as a goal, but there’s still no reason to make a new extra `embedding_matrix` when that already exists inside the `.vectors` property.

Comment: Thx, lastly, In embedding_layer (I mentioned in the comment), my vocab_size is 43 from `vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1`. My **embeddings_dictionary.vectors** has the shape of (412457, 400). It says `Layer weight shape (43, 100) not compatible with provided weight shape (412457, 400)` What can I do?

Comment: There's no information about what your `tokenizer` object might be, and 43 words seems pretty small for a set of word-vectors. Meanwhile, a word-vector set of ~413K words of 400 dimensions each sounds more typical. So the problem is likely in your `tokenizer`. To guess what's going wrong, I'd need far more info, and it sounds like a very different problem than your question above. So I suggest posting a new question, with full details about: (1) what you're attempting to do; (2) example code; (3) the full error message/stack.

Comment: (But most generally: if you want to use a pretrained 413K-word-long set of word-vectors with your `embedding_layer`, the `embedding_layer` should have a vocabulary of 413K words too -- not just 43!)

Answer (score 1):

It does not have a get method, change it to like this : `embeddings_dictionary[word]`